# Android loading activity in splashscreen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

I have a splashscreen which downloads some files from my webserver.

After downloading I need to start the `mainactivity` which has to create many buttons at runtime and this needs some time.

Is it possible to start the `mainactivity` without showing it (so still show the splashscreen) and let the mainactivity its `@onCreate()` and after it is finished then show the mainactivity?
I think changing `setContentView` may not work because the buttons need the root layout of the mainactivity.

Comment: I suggest you to use fragments, the splashscreen in a fragment and the mainactivity in an other (which will be one activity) then the two fragments will load simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **NO**.

`onCreate` only call when your activity start.
I suggest you to use only one activity with two fragments ( Splash `fragment`  and   Main `fragment` ).

First, you start activity and show splash fragment. When splash fragment finish, you show the main fragment.

It's faster than 2 activity, I'm sure that.